# Drawing nested elements on canvas in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem in displaying nested elements on canvas . 
So my Datastructure looks like the following: 
(Node class is a rectangle on canvas)
Nodelist:(contains an observable collection of NODEs)
       Nodes: nodes contains Connections which means it has classes and each class has two point : source and destination 
    And i can draw the rectangles(nodes) on canvas but i cannot draw lines on the same canvas . 
    The problem is with the following: --the lines represents a nested data in Node class and i have only one datatemplate in itemstemplate? 
    Can anybody suggest a sulution , how could i display the lines on the canvas?

```
Below is the problematic xaml code
```

Thanks

```
<ItemsControl Name="drawAreaControl" ItemsSource="{Binding NodeList}" >
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="Connection">
                    <Line X1="{Binding Destination.X}" Y1="{Binding Destination.Y}"
                                      X2="{Binding Source.X}" Y2="{Binding Source.Y}"
                                        Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3"/>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding CanvasPosition.X}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding CanvasPosition.Y}" />

                </Style>

            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>    



            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >

                <DataTemplate  DataType="SimpleNode">

                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="Connection">
                                <Canvas><Line X1="{Binding Destination.X}" Y1="{Binding Destination.Y}"
                                      X2="{Binding Source.X}" Y2="{Binding Source.Y}"
                                        Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3"/>
                                </Canvas>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

                    <Rectangle 
                        Uid="{Binding ID}" Name="dropNode"  Width="30"   Height="30"    MouseDown="dropNode_MouseDown" MouseRightButtonDown="dropNode_MouseRightButtonDown" GotFocus="dropNode_GotFocus"  Focusable="True" LostFocus="dropNode_LostFocus" MouseEnter="dropNode_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="dropNode_MouseLeave" >


                    </Rectangle>




                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                    <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" Name="dropCanvas" AllowDrop="True"  Drop="dropcanvas_Drop"  MouseMove="dropCanvas_MouseMove" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" DragEnter="dropCanvas_DragEnter"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Gray" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Don't use bindings to set Canvas.Left and Top in your style!

Comment: Without them  every item would be in the same position